# Importing XML to access vba adding closing tag in file

Tags: xml, vba, ms-access

I'm trying to import an XML file into access.
However it is in a format that is not suitable for access. I have to automate it as part of an import routine. I cant work out how to add the end tag in VBA.
Supplied XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <field name="Field1">1</field>
            <field name="Field2">for</field>
            <field name="Field3">TEST</field>
        </row>
    </rows>
</root>
```

I changed the XML to the following with VBA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<rows>
    <row>
        <Field1>1
        <Field2>for
        <Field3>TEST
    </row>
</rows>
</root>
```

But I need it to be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<rows>
    <row>
        <Field1>1</Field1>
        <Field2>for</Field2>
        <Field3>TEST</Field3>
    </row>
</rows>
</root>
```

VBA used:

```vb
Dim sBuf As String
Dim sTemp As String
Dim iFileNum As Integer
Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\f5.xml"   'file location
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Input As iFileNum
Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
  Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
  sTemp = sTemp & sBuf & vbCrLf
Loop
Close iFileNum
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "</field>", "")  ' removes closing tags
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<field name=""Field1"">", "<Field1>")
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<field name=""Field2"">", "<Field2>")
sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<field name=""Field3"">", "<Field3>")
iFileNum = FreeFile
Open sFileName For Output As iFileNum
Print #iFileNum, sTemp
Close iFileNum

End Sub
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Added full XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
<rows>
    <row>
        <field name="OrderType">1</field>
        <field name="CustAccRef">JOE1</field>
        <field name="CustomerOrderNumber">TEST</field>
        <field name="OrderDate">22/04/2013</field>
        <field name="DelPostalName">Joe Bloggs</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine1">House 1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine2">Street1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine3">Area1</field>
        <field name="DelPostcode">AA1 AA1</field>
        <field name="DelContact">Name of contact</field>
        <field name="DelTelephone">0101010101</field>
        <field name="DelEmail">joe@host.com</field>
        <field name="DelCountryCode">GB</field>
        <field name="LineType">1</field>
        <field name="ProductCode">144</field>
        <field name="ProductDescription"></field>
        <field name="Warehouse">WH1</field>
        <field name="Quantity">1</field>
        <field name="UnitPrice"></field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="OrderType">1</field>
        <field name="CustAccRef">JOE1</field>
        <field name="CustomerOrderNumber">TEST</field>
        <field name="OrderDate">22/04/2013</field>
        <field name="DelPostalName">Joe Bloggs</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine1">House 1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine2">Street1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine3">Area1</field>
        <field name="DelPostcode">AA1 AA1</field>
        <field name="DelContact">Name of contact</field>
        <field name="DelTelephone">0101010101</field>
        <field name="DelEmail">joe@host.com</field>
        <field name="DelCountryCode">GB</field>
        <field name="LineType">1</field>
        <field name="ProductCode">10000070</field>
        <field name="ProductDescription"></field>
        <field name="Warehouse">WH1</field>
        <field name="Quantity">20</field>
        <field name="UnitPrice"></field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="OrderType">1</field>
        <field name="CustAccRef">JOE1</field>
        <field name="CustomerOrderNumber">TEST</field>
        <field name="OrderDate">22/04/2013</field>
        <field name="DelPostalName">Joe Bloggs</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine1">House 1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine2">Street1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine3">Area1</field>
        <field name="DelPostcode">AA1 AA1</field>
        <field name="DelContact">Name of contact</field>
        <field name="DelTelephone">0101010101</field>
        <field name="DelEmail">joe@host.com</field>
        <field name="DelCountryCode">GB</field>
        <field name="LineType">3</field>
        <field name="ProductCode">Delivery</field>
        <field name="ProductDescription"></field>
        <field name="Warehouse"></field>
        <field name="Quantity"></field>
        <field name="UnitPrice">2.95</field>
    </row>
    <row>
        <field name="OrderType">1</field>
        <field name="CustAccRef">JOE1</field>
        <field name="CustomerOrderNumber">TEST</field>
        <field name="OrderDate">22/04/2013</field>
        <field name="DelPostalName">Joe Bloggs</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine1">House 1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine2">Street1</field>
        <field name="DelAddressLine3">Area1</field>
        <field name="DelPostcode">AA1 AA1</field>
        <field name="DelContact">Name of contact</field>
        <field name="DelTelephone">0101010101</field>
        <field name="DelEmail">joe@host.com</field>
        <field name="DelCountryCode">GB</field>
        <field name="LineType">4</field>
        <field name="ProductCode"></field>
        <field name="ProductDescription">Comments for someone</field>
        <field name="Warehouse"></field>
        <field name="Quantity"></field>
        <field name="UnitPrice"></field>
    </row>
</rows>
```

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/369403). You actually want to parse the input after importing it. Modifying the XML file without an XML parser is a terrible plan, and importing to a temporary table, then formatting the data as desired is a way better plan.

Comment: Alternatively, the standard to transform XML documents from one format to another is [XSLT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT). You can use XSLT documents with VBA using the MSXML object.

Comment: Hi Erik. Thank you for the advise. I have started to read up on XSLT when I was stuck with this. However have not progressed very far. I have tried to import the original XML into access, but it wont import, it just shows one field empty. I think access only accepts the <open tag> data</close tag> type of XML.

Comment: Well... If you actually tell me how you want it imported (and perhaps share a longer sample, are there multiple `<row>` tags and do you want one row per row tag?) I can actually answer this. Now, I can only try to make your bad plan work, or provide a full xslt solution, while manually importing into Access using MSXML is often easier than relying on an xlst and the `ImportXML` function.

Comment: Hi Erik. Thank you for your help. It would be 19 fields, with four records. Its going into SLQ server and I'm picking up any new file that has changed, or does not match any previous file names. With a runtime on the server to scan and import.

Comment: Ah, that full content makes it a lot clearer. Do you already have a table created, and do you want to append, or do you want to create a new table based on this XML? The `name` attribute corresponds with the field name, and the content with the field content, right? (If you want to create new fields, using xslt and `ImportXML` might be your best bet, since that auto-detects field type)

Comment: Hi Erik I would append in the end, but I can just import into a temp table and then run a quick append query after. Your assumption about the field names and content is correct. Sorry for not making it clear in the beginning. I'm not using the XML for anything else only to format it to import into access.

Comment: I see parfait already has written up quite a good answer. Ping me if there are still things you need help with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), a special purpose, declarative language (like SQL) designed to transform source XML files to other XML, HTML, even txt/csv for end-use needs. For MS Access' end use needs, specifically the [ImportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-importxml-method-access) method, XML must be element-centric (i.e, all attributes are ignored) with field names as node names and repeating root children as table name.

Below XSLT walks down the tree and migrates the attribute's *name* to element's name and retains same field value. NOTE: Processing assumes `<root>` was redundantly added to top and `<rows>` is actually the root. If not, see comment where to change in XSLT.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file -a special well-formed xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/rows">  <!-- IF NEEDED CHANGE @match TO: /root/rows -->
    <Orders>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="row"/>
    </Orders>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <Order>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="field"/>
    </Order>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

MS Access **VBA**

```vb
Public Sub FieldNamesXMLImport()
On Error GoTo ErrHandle
    ' ADD MSXML, v6.0 REFERENCE UNDER TOOLS
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60, newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\Input.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    ' IMPORT TRANSFORMED XML
    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\Output.xml"

    MsgBox "Successfully imported transformed XML!", vbInformation

ExitHandle:
    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrHandle:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description, vbInformation
    Resume ExitHandle
End Sub
```

Transformed XML

[XSLT Fiddle Demo](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPqsHTo)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Orders>
    <Order>
        <OrderType>1</OrderType>
        <CustAccRef>JOE1</CustAccRef>
        <CustomerOrderNumber>TEST</CustomerOrderNumber>
        <OrderDate>22/04/2013</OrderDate>
        <DelPostalName>Joe Bloggs</DelPostalName>
        <DelAddressLine1>House 1</DelAddressLine1>
        <DelAddressLine2>Street1</DelAddressLine2>
        <DelAddressLine3>Area1</DelAddressLine3>
        <DelPostcode>AA1 AA1</DelPostcode>
        <DelContact>Name of contact</DelContact>
        <DelTelephone>0101010101</DelTelephone>
        <DelEmail>joe@host.com</DelEmail>
        <DelCountryCode>GB</DelCountryCode>
        <LineType>1</LineType>
        <ProductCode>144</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescription></ProductDescription>
        <Warehouse>WH1</Warehouse>
        <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        <UnitPrice></UnitPrice>
    </Order>
    ...
</Orders>
```

**Order** Table

[CodePen Table](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZRvEdx) *(html version of Access table)*

[image: Database Table Output]

Comment: Hi Parfait. Thank you very much for the solution and it works very nicely. It will also help as I can use the XSL to work through how it formats the code, and should I need to alter in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Happy coding!